# Jquery change class not working after animation

Tags: jquery

I think my question is really simple but I don't know why my jquery is not working.
I just want the navigation to slide in from top. By clicking the navIcon button again the navigation should hide and the classname of the button should change again.

Here is my code:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2sq3kst/)

HTML

```
<div class="navIcon navIconInactive"></div>
<div id="navWrapper"></div>
```

CSS

```
.navIconInactive {
position: fixed;
z-index: 4;
width: 36px;
height: 34px;
top: 20px;
right: 25px;
cursor: pointer;
background: green;
}
.navIconActive {
position: fixed;
z-index: 4;
width: 36px;
height: 34px;
top: 20px;
right: 25px;
cursor: pointer;
background: red;
}

#navWrapper {
position: fixed;
top: -70px;
height: 70px;
width: 100%;
background: #333;
z-index: 2;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('.navIconInactive').click(function() {
    $('#navWrapper').animate({
        top: '0'
    }, 250, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    if ( $('.navIcon').hasClass('navIconInactive') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('navIconInactive').addClass('navIconActive');
        }
});

$('.navIconActive').click(function() {
    $('#navWrapper').animate({
        top: '-70'
    }, 250, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    if ( $('.navIcon').hasClass('navIconActive') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('navIconActive').addClass('navIconInactive');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You have to `removeClass` / `addClass` after animation finishes and hence put it inside animation function. 
As you are binding `click` events for active / inactive `div` using `class` selectors. But these class selectors are available dynamically when you add / remove classes and hence bind click event using `.on()` as we do for dynamic elements.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click",'.navIconInactive',function() {
       var navIcon = $(this);
       $('#navWrapper').animate({
                top: '0'
        }, 250, function() {
           $(navIcon).removeClass('navIconInactive').addClass('navIconActive');
        });
    });


   $(document).on("click",'.navIconActive',function() {
        var navIcon = $(this);
        $('#navWrapper').animate({
            top: '-70'
        }, 250, function() {      
           $(navIcon).removeClass('navIconActive').addClass('navIconInactive');
        });
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/g2sq3kst/9/)**

Comment: `$(this)` after animate is `$('#navWrapper')`, not `$('.navIcon')`

Comment: Thanks for your help. But your jsfiddle is also not working. When I click on navIcon button again the div should slide to top: -70px

Answer (score 0):

Do this after animation. You just need to change `$(this)` inside if to `$('.navIcon')`

```
$('.navIconInactive').click(function() {
    $('#navWrapper').animate({
        top: '0'
    }, 250, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        if( $('.navIcon').hasClass('navIconInactive') ) {
            $('.navIcon').removeClass('navIconInactive').addClass('navIconActive');
        }
    });
});

$('.navIconActive').click(function() {
    $('#navWrapper').animate({
        top: '-70'
    }, 250, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        if ( $('.navIcon').hasClass('navIconActive') ) {
            $('.navIcon').removeClass('navIconActive').addClass('navIconInactive');
        }
    });

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/niezbor/g2sq3kst/7/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But your jsfiddle is also not working. When I click on navIcon button again the div should slide to top: -70px